# How to send a mail via ruby with mail gem?

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, rubygems

I try to send a simple mail with the ruby mail gem:

```
require 'mail'

options = { :address              => "smtp.1und1.de",
            :port                 => 465,
            :domain               => 'xyz.info',
            :user_name            => 'abc@xyz.info',
            :password             => 'yessss',
            :authentication       => 'login',
            :enable_starttls_auto => true  }



Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end

Mail.deliver do
       to 'info@xyz.de'
     from 'info@xyz.de'
  subject 'testing sendmail'
     body 'testing sendmail'
end
```

but all I get ist the following error:

```
*H:\04_PRUPLA\12_RUBY_TOOLS\21_MAILER>ruby MAILER_001.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from MAILER_001.rb:17:in `<main>'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/mail.rb:133:in `deliver'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/message.rb:262:in `deliver'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/message.rb:2159:in `do_delivery'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:100:in `deliver!'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:109:in `start_smtp_session'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/smtp.rb:518:in `start'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/smtp.rb:553:in `do_start'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/smtp.rb:954:in `critical'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/smtp.rb:553:in `block in do_start'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/smtp.rb:944:in `recv_response'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill': end of file reached (EOFError)*
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/639 I know it's for an older version of the gem, but give it a shot.

Comment: Hey anothermh, that's it! Thank you very very much! eric.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this guide:

https://github.com/mikel/mail#usage

I think you should use A Mail.new class to create a "new" mail before send it.